# Python multiprocessing messaging code

Tags: python

I am just learning how to do some multiprocessing with Python, and I would like to create a non-blocking chat application that can add/retrieve messages to/from a database. This is my somewhat primitive attempt (note: It is simplified for the purposes of this post); however, I would like to know how close/far off off the mark I am. Any comments, revisions, suggestions, etc. are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import time

# Get all past messages
def batch_messages():
    # The messages list here will be attained via a db query
    messages = [">> This is a message.", ">> Hello, how are you doing today?", ">> Really good!"]
    for m in messages:
        print m

# Add messages to the DB    
def add_messages(q):    

    # Retrieve from the queue
    message_to_add = q.get()

    # For testing purposes only; perfrom another DB query to add the message to the DB
    print "(Add to DB)"

# Recieve new, inputted messages.
def receive_new_message(q, new_message):

    # Add the new message to the queue:
    q.put(new_message)

    # Print the message to the screen
    print ">>", new_message

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Set up the queue
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Print the past messages
    batch_messages()

    while True: 
        # Enter a new message
        input_message = raw_input("Type a message: ")

        # Set up the processes
        p_add = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_messages, args=(q,))
        p_rec = multiprocessing.Process(target=receive_new_message, args=(q, input_message,))

        # Start the processes   
        p_rec.start()
        p_add.start()

        # Let the processes catch up before printing "Type a message: " again. (Shell purposes only)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That's quite odd that it works fine when I run it...I will look further into this. But, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I can explicitly pass it to the functions that require it, and then I assume it will work for as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, you should pass `q` as a parameter.

Comment: `q` is now passed to the functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't create a new process for every task. Put a loop in `add_messages`; `q.get` will wait for the next task in the queue.
- `receive_new_message` is not doing anything useful in your example. Place `q.put(new_message)` right after `raw_input` instead.

:

```
def add_messages(q):    
    while True:
        # Retrieve from the queue
        message_to_add = q.get()
        print "(Add to DB)"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p_add = multiprocessing.Process(target=add_messages, args=(q,))
    p_add.start()

    while True: 
        input_message = raw_input("Type a message: ")

        # Add the new message to the queue:
        q.put(input_message)

        # Let the processes catch up before printing "Type a message: " again. (Shell purposes only)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the revision! I appreciate your help. On a side note, I included the `receive_new_message` process with the thought that I would need to output messages from the queue to users' screens, and that this process should be separate from the `add_messages` (to the db) process. Is this "concern" a necessary one? Or can the outputting to the screen be coupled with the database querying?

Comment: @JohnZ If you need the two subprocesses, you would use two queues. For example, `receive_new_message` might read from `q1`, do some processing and forward the results to `add_messages` via `q2`.

Comment: Ahhh okay. That makes sense. Thank you for the feedback!